# How to check that the file downloaded is extension .zip on the machine where test cafe is running

Tags: testing, automation, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

the following code performs a click on Download button and that action downloads a file on the "client machine". Actualy the "client machine" is a docker - debian image that download chrome and runs test cafe 1.9.2.

```
public static async DownloadMonitor() {
    await t.click(monitorDetailPageSelector.contextMenu)
    await t.wait(WaitConfig.Waits.second)
    await t.click(monitorDetailPageSelector.downloadButton)
    await t.wait(WaitConfig.Waits.second)
   return true; 
  }
```

After this test i want to verify that the file downloaded is .zip extension.

Problems that i have

I do not know the download folder on the client machine.

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve a downloaded filename from the 'content-disposition' header by using [RequestLogger](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/guides/advanced-guides/intercept-http-requests.html#log-http-requests) API. The example from [How to check downloaded file name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58657559/how-to-check-downloaded-file-name) thread demonstrates this approach.

Also, to control the download directory path, intercept a download request and manually save a file. Take a look at the solution from this thread: [Download file - Save popup in Internet Explorer using TestCafe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54284722/download-file-save-popup-in-internet-explorer-using-testcafe/54308667#54308667)